# Declaration of MapView (ArcGIS for Android) Center and Zoom

Tags: java, android

I am begginer in java and ArcGIS for android. I want to make simple app with `MapView`.

I have problem with declaration of `MapView` center and Zoom. I need to do it programmatically (application startup) in java file, not in xml file. I will try explain it on on simple example.

Problem is in `mMapView.setMapOptions(options);` I need to do in `onCreate()`, if I make `Button` with `mMapView.setMapOptions(options);` everything is OK. I searched solution in samples and on the internet, but I think, that I do not know how to ask on it.

Sorry for my english and thank you for your comments.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.esri.android.map.MapOptions;
import com.esri.android.map.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MapView mMapView = null;
    Button b1;

    MapOptions options = new MapOptions(MapOptions.MapType.TOPO, 49.591241, 17.255503, 16);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        //mMapView.centerAndZoom(49.591241, 17.255503, 8);
        btnClick();

        mMapView.setMapOptions(options);

        mMapView.setAllowRotationByPinch(true);
        mMapView.setRotationAngle(25);

        mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);
    }

    public void btnClick() {
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //mMapView.centerAndZoom(49.591241, 17.255503, 10);
                mMapView.setMapOptions(options);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Call MapView.pause to suspend map rendering while the activity is paused, which can save battery usage.
        mMapView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Call MapView.unpause to resume map rendering when the activity returns to the foreground.
        mMapView.unpause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the `MapView` declaration from your XML and create it inside the activity.  Then just add the `MapView` to your layout.

XML (details omitted)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mapLayout"></LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  MapView mapView = MapView(MainActivity.this, mapOpts);
  // other logic/initializations

  ViewGroup mapLayout = findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);
  mapLayout.addView(mapView); // might have to specify index param if you need buttons
```

Comment: Thanks for great idea, my solution I post below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution by previous answer. Thanks zec!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.esri.android.map.MapOptions;
import com.esri.android.map.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MapView mMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapOptions options = new MapOptions(MapOptions.MapType.TOPO, 49.591241, 17.255503, 16);

        mMapView = new MapView(MainActivity.this, options);
        setContentView(mMapView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Call MapView.pause to suspend map rendering while the activity is paused, which can save battery usage.
        mMapView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Call MapView.unpause to resume map rendering when the activity returns to the foreground.
       mMapView.unpause();
    }

}
```